# TableView with dynamic UISwitches - how to identify the switches

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have searched a lot for my problem but I still couldn`t resolve it.
I`m trying to dynamically add some UISwitches to a TableView and change some Data depending on their state. 
Adding the switches works fine for me with the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...
UISwitch *aSwitch = [[[UISwitch alloc] init] autorelease];
[aSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[cell.contentView addSubview:aSwitch];

return cell;
```

}

My problem is - (void) switchChanged:(id)sender. How can I identify which switch has been changed to modify the correct corresponding data?

Comment: Not related to the question, since it's been answered comprehensively already, but the segment of code-style text in your first sentence is because you've use the back tick character (`) as an apostrophe. On StackOverflow you can enclose a section of your text in back ticks to get code style without a paragraph break. Stick to apostrophes (') for normal text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the tag property of *UIView* (*UISwitch* inherits from *UIView*):

```
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger tag
```

This case is exactly the sort of thing this property was designed to solve. When you're dynamically creating the switches, you can just increment a static variable.

Then in your `- (void) switchChanged:(id)sender` method you can simply check the value of the tag. :)

Comment: That was exactly what I`m searching for. Tanks a lot!

Comment: incrementing a static variable? This will only work if he uses `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` like it was **NOT** designed.

Comment: Actually, I think this may NOT work if `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is used because you could dequeue cells, in which case the tag may be incorrect. The design of the app needs to figure out how the controls *should be* identified. I think the issue here is about how the controls *can be* identified.

Answer (score 2):

first you should change your method so the cell is reused properly. you want to use something like this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        UISwitch *aSwitch = [[[UISwitch alloc] init] autorelease];
        aSwitch.tag = 23;
        [aSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:aSwitch];
    }
    UISwitch *aSwitch = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:23];
    aSwitch.on = whatever;
    // Configure the cell...
    return cell;
}
```

and then you can get the indexpath of the changed switch like this:

```
- (void) switchChanged:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *switch = (UISwitch *)sender;
    UIView *contentView = [switch superview];
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[contentView superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UISwitch *switch = (UISwitch *)sender;
UIView *contentView = [switch superview];
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[contentView superview];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self tableView] indexPathForCell:cell];
```

This will give you the indexPath. You could also set `aSwitch.tag = indexPath.row` if you've got one data source.